# Open a Matplotlib figure from Windows10 through SSH tunnel of vscode

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code, remote-server

My remote PC os is Windows10, and I want to use plot() to get the figure from my remote PC. There're a lot of answers is base on linux. I don't know how solve this problem. I will be appreciate if someone could help me.

Comment: Can you explain the problem in more detail? In which part is the difficulty encountered at present? Can't establish SSH connection with windows10 or can't get graphics. A detailed description can help me determine the solution to the problem more accurately.

Comment: I can establish SSH connection by vscode, but I can't get graphics by using function plt.show()

Comment: Is there any error reporting prompt